# AzureBlobStorageContainer FetchAttributes() throwing an error despite the exact same input working in another situation

Tags: .net, azure, azure-blob-storage, .net-6.0, .net-framework-version

I have three projects. One is a .NET Framework website and one is a .NET 6 website. Both of these websites are using the 3rd project running .NET Framework to upload files onto our Azure blob storage.

Files submitted from the .NET 6 website throw the following error. Files from the .NET Framework website do not throw this error.

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly System.Data.Services.Client, Version=3.5.0.0
```

I have stepped through the upload beginning to end from both websites. They provide *identical* information. I checked the value of every single variable along the way and there are no differences. The *only* difference is that one website is using .NET 6 and the other is using .NET Framework. But that shouldn't matter as both websites are providing identical information to the 3rd project.

The error is thrown when we call .FetchAttributes() on a AzureBlobStorageProvider object while initializing the container in the 3rd project.

I am at a total loss of where to go from here and would appreciate any suggestions. I cannot fathom how two identical inputs are causing two different outcomes.

Answer (score 1):

Here are few workarounds that you can try:

**Solution 1:**

1. Update the Visual Studio to the most recent version.
2. Eliminate every binding redirect in `web.config`
3. Include the following in the `.csproj` file:

   ```cs
   <PropertyGroup>
     <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
     <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
   </PropertyGroup>
   ```
4. Build the project.
5. The `(WebAppName).dll.config` file should be located in the `bin` folder.  It should contain redirects; copy them to the `web.config` file.
6. Delete the previous snippet from the file `.csproj`

**Solution 2:**

Try adding `<UseNETCoreGenerator>true</UseNETCoreGenerator>`  to your `.csproj` file:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    ...
    <UseNETCoreGenerator>true</UseNETCoreGenerator>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Note: Make sure that you are using .net 6 with there supported package versions ,if not please try to update .

**Reference:**
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-vs-build-sdk/issues/160

Comment: No luck. The first solution didn't generate any files. And the second one gave the same result. But thanks anyway for the suggestions.